# iPhone view in Interface builder is too large

Tags: iphone, view, interface-builder

My problem is that every view, that I am creating is too large.

here are some examples:
[image: Tab bar in IB]
Tab bar in IB:
[image: Tab Bar on iPhone]
[Tab Bar on iPhone:
This problem occurs in every of my views.
Does anybody know how I can solve that?

Best regards
Melanie

Comment: What size of view does the interface designer report you're making? Are you changing this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot, it looks like you've tried to put a `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController`. According to the docs, you shouldn't do this. It may account for the strange sizing.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your XIB is iPhone xib rather then iPad

or

second think set your viewframe like below.

```
yourview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
```